# Factorials in Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to do this problem without multiplying it out or is that the easiest way to do this question?
$$\begin{align}6! = 6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1 &\equiv 720 &\mod 7 \\&\equiv 6 &\mod 7\end{align}$$

Comment: [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

Comment: 6=-1 mod 7, so without multiplying, you can do -5*4*3*2*1, see if you can apply a similar trick again

Answer (score 1):

Motivated by the proof of Wilson's theorem, you might note that
$5 \cdot 3 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ and $4 \cdot 2 \equiv 1 \mod 7$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the multiplication easier by reducing the product $\mod7$ as you go along. Thus $6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1\equiv -1\times-1\times-1\times1\equiv -1 \equiv 6 \mod7$, because $5\times4 \equiv -1\mod7$ and $3\times2 \equiv -1\mod7$.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method is to try and get squares$$\begin{align}6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1&\equiv (-1)\times(-2)\times(-3)\times3\times2\times1\mod 7\\&\equiv (-1^2)\times(-2^2)\times(-3^2)\\&\equiv-( 1\times4\times2)\\&\equiv-8\\&\equiv 6\mod 7\end{align}$$